Pentaho PDI is processing rules fast while from wildlfy its becoming very slow
Pentaho ETL rule is picking up data from a table and pushing data to a different table (will be another database). While running in Pentaho PDI (Spoon) was able to read and inject 1 million records in 10 seconds. Same rules (kjb/ktr files) when I provide to kettle-jars running in my Wildfly application for processing, I am observing its taking close to 90 minutes for just 100k records. Any help in this context?
Few points:

When run from Wildfly postgre cpu is getting overutilized (150%), same is not the case when its done from PDI UI from laptop on same database. So work_mem and few other db specific settings are ruled out, some change is needed in wildfly side itself
Wildly application is running in a container and postgre is as well a container based on zolando operator.
Post 50 minutes approximately, i see 100k records in database, but CPU continues to be over utilized and wildfly is also waiting.
No connection pools are used, batch size of insert statements is 50,000


There isn't really a way to guess what's happening here.  We don't have your application, we don't know how you're configured other than your poor connection pool management.
